# upload document URL as response in dailoglow

Tags: dialogflow-es, appian

Iwant to give user guide link as a response in dialog flow through custom payload. Does anyone know how it can be done. Also, i ll be using this chatbot in appian through web content component.

Answer (score 1):

You can create **Custom Payloads** from the Default response tab for the intent. The custom payloads are used for rich responses and have a json format.
In order to add a guide link to the user as you mentioned, add the below json format in the Custom Payloads section

The [info response type](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/dialogflow-messenger#info_response_type) is a simple title card that users can click or touch.

```
 {
  "richContent": [
    [
      {
        "type": "info",
        "title": "Info item title",
        "subtitle": "Info item subtitle",
        "image": {
          "src": {
            "rawUrl": "https://example.com/images/logo.png"
          }
        },
        "actionLink": "https://example.com"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Change the values with your needs and click in save Button.
There are different types of [rich content](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/dialogflow-messenger)  where you can add a URL, you can check the best “richContent ” option for your application.

If you will use the API, check the following “[Rich Response Message Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.intents#message)”.

Regarding with appian, follow-up this documentation, where you will be able to [integrate Dialogflow into your appian application](https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/21.2/icc/setting_up_google_dialogflow.html) and add the Custom Payloads response as is mentioned before.